# ref.map is not a function?

Tags: node.js, react-redux

this is my first post. Thank you all for the years, of assistance btw, I hope to pour in, as much as I've gotten from you guys/gals. Let's get started.

I have a Next.js / React-Redux application and here is my problem:

I'm attempting to update the Redux store, with JSON, that is returned from `fs.readFile' (the 'fs/promises' module:

//Product.js

```
function Product() {
   const suggested_products = useSelector((state) => state.user.suggested_products) // json read from /api/products
   const updateProducts = () => {
            (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(suggested_products)))?.map((product) =>  { // Compliler does not like this line
                <div>
                    <input type='checkbox'>
                      <p> {product.category}</p>
                      <p>{product.service_name}</p>
                    </input        
                </div>
            })
        }
        return (
            if (userSelectedProduct) ? updateProducts() : <p>No data found</p>
    }
```

//Form.js

```
import { useSWR } from 'swr'

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

function Form() {
  const [url, setURL] = useState('');
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);



  <input
    value={product}
    onChange={

       dispatch(updateCustomerCSP((JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.target.value)))));
                            setURL(`api/${product}/`); //Attempt to dynamically fetch data, from client side
                            dispatch(updateSuggestedProducts(data)); //Update data in store returned from client side fetching

                        }}
  </input>

}
```

// pages/api/products

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
export default function handler(req, res) {
   const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(),`/data.js'); // /data.js contains JSON array [{"product-1": "value"}, {"product-2": "value"}], which is why I need to use map function.
   try {
      const fileData = fs.readFile(filePath);
      const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fileData));
      res.status(200).json(data);
} catch (err)
   {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to load data' })
   }
}
```

// This error throws ref.map is not a function from the Products.js component.
Here is the only info that I could find in regards to ref's in React.
Also, the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify wrappers, are to keep Redux happy with object going into the store. Thanks for reading community, looking forward to your input. Should any oneed more info, please let me know. Also, here is info in regards to refs, that I could find:

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I would assume that the 'ref' is not an array, so it's unable to execute the map method on a non-array. Can you confirm what type/shape of data you're expected 'ref' to be?

Comment: It's hard to know with what you've presented here.  Try `console.log(suggested_products)` and `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(suggested_products))` -- is it always an array?

Comment: Hello every one, thanks for the replies. So I can confirm, the data is always an array structured as,

[ 
 {"product-1": "value-1"},
 {"product-2": "value-2"},
]

And i've been able to inject single objects into the Redux store using the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({object})). 

However, now that I need to actually perform map() on an array of objects, either gives me an empty object '{}', after reading the file, or it'll parse the file, and not let me use the map function on the {suggested_products} array in the Product.js component. Here is the best info to assist...will paste below:

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module |

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse | 

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side | 

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12124 |

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks |


All was helpful, but just can't quite piece it together unfortunately. Thank you in advance everyone.


Also, I do understand that .map is specifically for arrays, but again, I may be missing something here:

Comment: Lastly, here is the sequence of events that should make up the algorithm:

1. User picks category of the product they are looking for. (Form 1) | 

2. User picks the store that they would like to shop. (Form 2 - This should update form 3 showing array of products |

3. Component should update with array of products, based on category and store that has been provided by user input

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I actually had the input wrapped in a HOC, and the event handler wasn't properly registered to the input element itself., therefore failing to load in the array object into the store to use.

So be careful of that, when building your own components.

For instance,

```
function Component() {
  function loadArrayInStore() {
    loadInStore()
 }
  const MyButton = (props) => {
    <input  onChange={props.handler} // I had an inline handler here such as onChange={ (e)= { doNotLoadArrayInStoreAndDontWork()}
  } 
  return (
     <MyButton handler={loadArrayInStore} />
  )
}
```

So be watchful, when creating HOC's :)